# url rewrite using .htaccess to make friendly urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have 3 questions regarding .htaccess,

1- if i use .htaccess to rewrite the url's on my website does it affect any of the requests or do i need to change the link for all forms for example if a action post for a form is index.php?submit do i need to change that link ? when i for example hide .php extension in .htaccess or it doesn't affect it

2-how do i basically hide all .php extensions

3- if i have the below url

www.link.com/post.php?post_id=53&post_name=the-International-day-in-roma

a-)how do i make .htaccess rewrite it to the following

www.link.com/post/the-International-day-in-roma

b-)does it matter if there was commas or can i remove them also ?

www.link.com/post.php?post_id=53&post_name=everyday,-or-today,-or-tomorrow

Comment: One question per thread please

Comment: can you answer my third one please @anubhava

Comment: Sorry 3rd requirement is difficult because postId `53` is not in original URL `www.link.com/post/the-International-day-in-roma` so it is not possible to rewrite to `www.link.com/post.php?post_id=53&post_name=the-International-day-in-roma`

Comment: what do i need to do then ? remove the post_id=.. then i'll be able to do the rewrite ? if yes how ? @anubhava

Comment: `post_id` will be required in `post.php` for lookup. You can have pretty URL as: `www.link.com/post/53/the-International-day-in-roma`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope these answers might help :

(2)  I am responding to the second question first.  Use this code in your .HTACCESS file to remove PHP file extensions

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

(1)  For your first question........you may remove the PHP extensions from the file names. Doesn't change much anyway. Simply makes it easier for YOU, when writing your code.

(3)  Try this tutorial :

[HTACCESS Tutorial](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F)